# Firebase Sharing with Multiple Web Apps

Tags: firebase

We have an app that needs to be split into two separate websites(webapps). My solution was to just use 2 different firebases, but we're trying to share user data across both sites(user profile data, user content, etc).

Is it possible to use one firebase to support multiple sites?  Is this considered an accepted practice? Both apps are written in AngularJs.

Comment: Sure. Just put each web site in its own node under your <myid>.firebaseio.com. E.g. `http://ron.firebaseio.com/webapp1` and `http://ron.firebaseio.com/webapp2`.

Comment: Hi Frank, in your recommendation, should I put my users in http://ron.firebaseio.com/users for both apps?

Comment: If both web applications use the same set of users, I would indeed put them under a common/shared node. If each web application has its own set of users, I'd put them in a node under the respective web application's root node. That will make securing the webapp data later easier.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple apps, all of which share some common data, like their users, it is indeed reasonable to use a single Firebase to power all of them.

Your data structure might look something like this:

```
- Firebase root
  - users
  - app1
    - ... stuff ...
  - app2
    - ... stuff ...
```

This will have the benefit of making it easier to share any other overlapping data in the future.

On the downside, they share the same [quota / concurrents ceiling](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html), so managing billing might get tricky. If the identity of your users is indeed all that you're sharing between them, using the same login providers with [Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) might satisfy that need anyway. It would allow the same user to log in with twitter in both services and share a common `uid` across them.